# Convert this line of code from VB.NET to C#?

Tags: vb.net, c#-3.0

How do I convert the following line of code from VB.NET to C#.

```
Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
```

I got the following line from the developerfusion web site, but it's giving me wrong results in my program.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize + 1];
```

Here is an example of my entire code in Visual Basic.

```
Dim tcpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient()
TcpClient.Connect(txtIP.Text, txtPort.Text)

Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream()
If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then

    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtSend.Text.Trim())

    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    ' Read the NetworkStream into a byte buffer.
    TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 52428800 '50 MB

    'Do I need to clean the buffer?
    'Get the string back (response)
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    ' Output the data received from the host to the console.
    Dim returndata As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

Comment: Google of course! http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to the buffer size declaration?

Comment: That code is wrong. How can I translate this code Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic specifies the maximum bound of the array instead of the length of the array (arrays start at index 0), so your conversion added an extra byte. In your code however the correct way would be:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
```

If you get wrong results, tell us what exactly is wrong. Maybe it's another part of the code.

**Edit:** Remove the \0 like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
// Output the data received from the host to the console. 
string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRead);
```

**Edit:** Even better to read the data in packets, so you don't need to reserve a large buffer upfront:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4096]; //buffer
int bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
while(bytesRead>0)
{
    // Output the data received from the host to the console. 
    string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes,0,bytesRead);
    Console.Write(returndata);
    bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: In the return data I am getting a lot of 0\0\ characters . It seems that vb was able to remove all that when I was getting the data back from the socket but when I run the C# code I get a bunch of \0 characters. How can In handle that? \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\

Comment: networkStream.Read will return you the number of bytes it read, you can pass this to Encoding.ASCII.GetString as a parameter, so that you only convert the bytes actually read. Also you should be able to use the Trim command to remove remaining \0 character.

Comment: do you have by any chance an example on how to count the number of bytes and then passing the value to the encoding

Comment: Thank you so much! Pretty helpful since I was not trimming the data that I was receiving back from the socket. No I can apply this to all my sockets. Is there a better apporach to read my data instead of pre-assigning the 50MB to the receiving buffer. Please let me know.

Comment: YES! The normal way is to do this in a loop. You know that there is no data when the function returns 0 bytes read. But it depends a bit on what you want to do with the data later. Print on the console?

Comment: I am saving to the database but If you have an example to the console that you can send me that's fine I can adapt it.

Comment: Got it. And now that's my new way to do it. Thank you.